# Excel formulae for corresponding cells

Tags: excel

Hi I am trying to figure this out in excel for a while. I  need to write a formula in excel which will help me perform this seemingly difficult task. Let's say i have data in two columns like this

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
a 5
```

Basically I require excel to check for repetitive values in the 1st column (in this case a) and then check in the cells corresponding to that value(in this case cell 1 and cell 5) for specific conditions and if both the conditions are met it should give me true.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch this is not what you want, but seems to be one way of interpreting what you ask:

```
=IF(A1="A",OR(B1=1,B1=5))
```

in same row as start of data (assumed starts in A1) and copied down to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Formula for `C1`

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1,B1=1),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Substitute `B1=1` for your *specific conditions* and copy down as are as needed